# Define NameValue List in JSS

Tags: jss

I am just trying to define NameValueList in one of my JSS component. Looks like there are only defined set of fields available in CommonFieldTypes [@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-manifest]. Is there a way to define List Types [Name Value List] in JSS definition file and use in JSS Component. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> For custom Sitecore field types or other types not in the CommonFieldTypes enumeration, the string of their field type name in Sitecore (i.e. Single-Line Text) can be passed. Editors that support type annotations, like VS Code, will provide auto-completion on this enum.

Comment: I just tried in VS code, when i type NameValueList, it's not recognizing or auto completing.. Let me try to type the entire name and test the code..

Comment: @Gobinath, to use field types that are not defined in the `CommonFieldTypes` enum, you need to use the field type name as defined in Sitecore. For name value list field, the name is "Name Value List" in Sitecore.

Comment: @AdamWeber it works..